# MVC2 MSchart with detail grid

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid, mschart

I need the capability to display a chart, click on a region and display the details in a jqgrid on the same page. I tried using a pie Chart  and I can't seem to capture or create a click event for the chart.

The data points contain a .url property which I can redirect to a different page but I need to display details on the same page like a master-detail page.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that you receive success in using Microsoft ASP.NET Chart Controls, which can be used with MVC 1.0/2.0 on .NET 3.5 see http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2008/11/27/howto-use-the-new-aspnet-chart-controls-with-aspnet-mvc/ and which are included (in a new version) in ASP.NET 4.0.